# Force "File Save As" immediately after workbook opens -- code not executing

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I created a .xlsm wrkbk template with the code below (h/t mrexcel.com) embedded in a module in the macro-enabled template file.

To prevent users from overwriting the template file, the macro should execute immediately after file opens-- without end user manually calling the sub.

But the code is not executing. Your expert assistance is deeply appreciated!

Force "File Save As" when workbook opens

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

            Dim strNewFileName As String
            strNewFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=ThisWorkbook.Name & " A", FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xls), *.xls", FilterIndex:=1)

    IIf strNewFileName = "False" Then
                MsgBox "You must save a copy!"
                Workbook_Open
                Exit Sub

    End If
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strNewFileName

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't [save the file as a template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-as-a-template-58c6625a-2c0b-4446-9689-ad8baec39e1e])?

Comment: To put it a different way... You say template, but is your file *actually* a template, or just "a file you'd prefer people not mess with"? Your use of XLSM vs XLTM indicates it is the later. I find actual templates to be an often-unused feature of Office.

Comment: @T.J.L. - very insightful question. You are correct. It's a file for a weekly report that I don't want users changing until/unless the file is first saved with new name. Very sorry for the incorrect terminology.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Although I've been using Excel for over 15 years, I've never had occasion to use the formal template feature. You are, of course, absolutely correct, that the simple (and probably) best solution for me is to use `"file save as template`. Thanks so much for the suggestion. It will save me many hours of fix-it work. Any way I can up-vote your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is to [save your file as a template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-workbook-as-a-template-58c6625a-2c0b-4446-9689-ad8baec39e1e%5D)

Not that templates both without (`.XLTX`) and with (`.XLTM`) macro can be saved.